# How to set python environment variables in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytorch

I know how to add arguments for the Python script I want to run. For example, if `test.py` is my script file and it has one argument like `'--batch_size'` then I can edit `launch.json` in VS Code and set `"args": ["--batch_size", "32"]`

But I don't know how to add environmental arguments for Python itself. For example, Python has `-m` environmental variable, which runs library module as a script. If I want to run `python -m torch.distributed.launch test.py --batch_size 32`, what should I edit in VS Code to run the debugger?

**UPDATE**:
Here is my `launch.json`

[image]

Comment: -m is not environmental variable, it's just an argument too

Comment: I guess you are right, it is an argument for python itself but not for test.py. My problem is I dont know how to pass argument for python itself in VS code.

Answer (score 5):

-m is not environmental variable. It's just a regular argument.

To run `python -m torch.distributed.launch test.py --batch_size 32` use args  `"args": ["-m", "torch.distributes.launch" ,"--batch_size", "32"]` Also you need to run python itself instead of running script to pass these args to it (`"program": "python3"`).

To set actual environment variables use `"env": {"ENV_VAR_NAME1": "value of ENV_VAR_NAME1", "ENVVAR2": "Value for ENVVAR2"}`

[Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes) you can find more information about `launch.json` configuration

Comment: It says "File does not exist: "python3" "

Comment: Do you use python 2? How do you launch your script when it works?

Best way to answer is to attach your launch.json to your question

Comment: I have attached launch.json, please take a look

Comment: Future advice: it's not recommended to attach screenshots of code

About your launch.json
I guess it's correct, but most probably you can't launch `python` executable because it's not on your PATH variable in OS (I guess you're using windows)
You need to add path to your `python.exe` to PATH variable or just use full path to it in "program" attribute

Comment: I did that. Got "ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes" error

Comment: That is the another issue. At least you've launched python using launch.json. Also you better use ${file} in args instead of actual file name to be sure that path to file is correct when launching it

Comment: Also ensure that files is saved in UTF-8 encoding. This may be often cause of this error in VS Code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202377/discussion-between-paul-shishmarev-and-user3086871).

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone else is still stuck in the problem, I got it to work by replacing `"program"` with `"module"` and setting `"module"` parameter to `"torch.distributed.launch"` in the `launch.json` file. The `"args"` will then be set to `["--nproc_per_node", "2", "${file}"]`. Here I have 2 processes.

Answer (score -2):

You can just set the environment variables of your machine using:

```
export ENV_VAR_NAME='value'
```

or set the variable before executing the command.

```
ENV_VAR_NAME='value' test.py
```

Comment: I guess it's not going to be right answer at all.
Turns out that problem is with running python with additional arguments. Anyway, question about envvars was about how to configure VS code to launch code with envvars, not how to launch it with envvars from shell

Comment: Python debugger does not use current environment variable you set in terminal

Comment: No, exporting variables in bash does not pass them to python in VS Code (code-server) terminal. You need to switch to Jupyter Notebook or Lab if you want such simplicity:)